# problem-domain seems like a meta-tag - is it? Should it go?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, meta-tags

[problem-domain](/questions/tagged/problem-domain) is used in a couple of ways - but it seems it's just another meta-tag. Should it be removed from the relevant questions, of which there are 10 at the moment of writing?

Comment: I love this [facebook support question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071769/cant-log-facebook-through-google-chromo).. I guess the website domain has a problem?

Comment: Yeah. Sometimes it seems to be just a substitute for wanting to write "problem" somewhere.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-completed]?

Comment: @Doorknob: What makes you think this is completed? We still have 5 questions that are close targets, only when those are gone would the tag be gone..

Comment: I love how [meta-tag:burninate-request] is a tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should definitely go.

I've voted to close most of them, and am removing the tag from the remainder. There are now 5 left over, let's see if we can get rid of those (close, then delete).

Current status: We are down to 3 questions:

- [Using a non-English ubiquitous language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574942/using-a-non-english-ubiquitous-language) (3 close votes)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457179/is-it-harder-to-learn-a-new-problem-domain-or-a-new-language (closed, 1 delete vote)
- [Does anyone write really long, complex PHP apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173057/does-anyone-write-really-long-complex-php-apps-and-if-so-what-is-your-problem) (2 close votes)

Comment: I could just as easily have done it myself (the edits, that is), but I was unsure of the usefulness of the tag. Thought it best to ask first. =)

Comment: @J.Steen: Great that you asked! Now we can pool our collective attention on the tag and get those questions cleaned out together!

Comment: Huzzah for communi- I mean, democracy!

Comment: I'll oil up the guillotine! *Off* with their heads! Pitchforks! Torches! .... uhm ... tad too much perhaps?

Comment: Just a bit. I've done my part in the general mob now (voted the remaining to close). ;)